# HAL_SPI_Transmit is returning HAL_ERROR

Tags: stm32, spi, hal, stm32cubeide, slave

I´m trying to send and recibe data from a SPI Slave in Full-Duplex mode using HAL librarys and I´m struggling with a problem that I don´t know how to solve.

I'm having an issue with my SPI Slave code that utilizes interrupts. I have implemented the HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback function, which is called by the SPI interrupt. Inside this function, I activate the FlagIRQ to initiate the transmission of the tx buffer. However, when I use the HAL_SPI_Transmit function, it returns HAL_ERROR and doesn't transmit anything.

I have already sent 18 bytes of data, where 9 bytes are for the receiving function and the other 9 bytes are for the transmission of the slave. Based on this, I expected it to work correctly.

```
#include "main.h"


SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_spi1_rx;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_spi1_tx;


void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);


#define SPI_TIMEOUT 50000

uint8_t spi_tx_data[9];
uint8_t spi_rx_data[9];
int FlagIRQ = 0;



int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();


  SystemClock_Config();


  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();

  spi_tx_data[0] = 0x34;
  spi_tx_data[1] = 0x34;
  spi_tx_data[2] = 0x34;
  spi_tx_data[3] = 0x34;
  spi_tx_data[4] = 0x09;
  spi_tx_data[5] = 0x05;
  spi_tx_data[6] = 0x05;
  spi_tx_data[7] = 0x00;
  spi_tx_data[8] = 0x02;

  while (1)
  {
     HAL_SPI_Receive_IT(&hspi1, spi_rx_data, 9);
    

      if (FlagIRQ==1){
          if (HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, spi_tx_data, 9, SPI_TIMEOUT)!= HAL_OK){
              Error_Handler();
          }
          FlagIRQ=0;
        

      }
  }
```

}

```
void HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi1)
{

    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_10); //Toggle the led to see if we detect any  SPI signal.
    FlagIRQ= 1;
    }
}
```

I´ve also checked that the spi inicalization is correct:  SPI_POLARITY_LOW and SPI_PHASE_1EDGE for mode 0, that is the same that I´ve configured in the master.

```
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 1 */
  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_INPUT;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 2 */

}
```

I´ have checked also that the SPI signal from the master is correct, and as you can see in the screenshot below, it seems good abd the pins are properly connected.
[SPI Signal from the Master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZIYB.jpg)

Do anybody have an idea of what could be happening and why HAL fuctions are returning error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Slave can only transmit when Master transmits as well as only the Master can generate the clock.

Comment: yes, this is the reason why I send 18 bytes of data

Comment: You could maybe use `HAL_SPI_GetError()` to get more information about the error. Then look at the implementation of `HAL_SPI_Transmit()` to see what would cause it.